# Ubuntu shell scripting

Tags: bash, sh, dash-shell

What is the difference between different shells in Ubuntu:

```
$ cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
```

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate, let us know if anything else is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

> **Bash**
>
> Bash is the GNU Project's shell. Bash is the Bourne Again SHell. Bash
>   is an sh-compatible shell that incorporates useful features from the
>   Korn shell (ksh) and C shell (csh). It is intended to conform to the
>   IEEE POSIX P1003.2/ISO 9945.2 Shell and Tools standard. It offers
>   functional improvements over sh for both programming and interactive
>   use. In addition, most sh scripts can be run by Bash without
>   modification.
>
> The improvements offered by Bash include:
>
> ```
> Command line editing
> Unlimited size command history
> Job Control
> Shell Functions and Aliases
> Indexed arrays of unlimited size
> Integer arithmetic in any base from two to sixty-four.
> ```

<sup>Source:[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)</sup>

> **Dash**
>
> Dash is an acronym for Debian Almquist shell (dash). It is a Unix and
>   Linux shell which is much smaller than bash but still aiming at
>   POSIX-compliancy. dash is a POSIX-compliant implementation of /bin/sh
>   that aims to be as small as possible. dash is a direct descendant of
>   the NetBSD version of ash (the Almquist SHell), ported to Linux in
>   early 1997. It was renamed to dash in 2002.
>
> dash is the standard command interpreter for the Linux system. The
>   current version of dash is in the process of being changed to conform
>   with the POSIX 1003.2 and 1003.2a specifications for the shell. This
>   version has many features which make it appear similar in some
>   respects to the Korn shell, but it is not a Korn shell clone. Only
>   features designated by POSIX, plus a few Berkeley extensions, are
>   being incorporated into this shell.

<sup>Source:[2](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-binbash-vs-bindash-vs-binshshell/)</sup>

> **RBash**
>
> If Bash is started with the name rbash, or the --restricted or -r
>   option is supplied at invocation, the shell becomes restricted. A
>   restricted shell is used to set up an environment more controlled than
>   the standard shell. A restricted shell behaves identically to bash
>   with the exception that the following are disallowed or not performed:
>
> ```
> Changing directories with the cd builtin.
> Setting or unsetting the values of the SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV variables.
> Specifying command names containing slashes.
> Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the . builtin command.
> Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the -p option to the hash builtin command.
> Importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup.
> Parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at startup.
> Redirecting output using the ‘>’, ‘>|’, ‘<>’, ‘>&’, ‘&>’, and ‘>>’ redirection operators.
> Using the exec builtin to replace the shell with another command.
> Adding or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin.
> Using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins.
> Specifying the -p option to the command builtin.
> Turning off restricted mode with ‘set +r’ or ‘set +o restricted’.
> ```
>
> These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.
>
> When a command that is found to be a shell script is executed (see
>   Shell Scripts), rbash turns off any restrictions in the shell spawned
>   to execute the script.

<sup>Source:[3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html)</sup>

> **sh**
>
> sh is the command name of the Bourne shell, the standard command
>   language interpreter of Unix and many Unix-like operating systems,
>   including Linux. sh is a command language interpreter that executes
>   commands read from a command line string, the standard input, or a
>   specified file.
>
> The Bourne shell was developed in 1977 by Stephen Bourne at AT&T's
>   Bell Labs in 1977. It was the default shell of Unix Version 7. Most
>   Unix-like systems contain the file /bin/sh that is either the Bourne
>   shell, or a symbolic link (or hard link) to a compatible shell.

<sup>Source:[4](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ush.htm)</sup>

Comment: Current posix versions call `sh` the standard shell, sometimes also called POSIX Shell, “Bourne Shell” is of historic interest only.